# Not able to open URL with filter

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to open a Tableau dashboard with a filter on with HTML but it does not work!

I don't know how to use a variable in a HTML document.
What am i doing wrong?

Here is the HTML:

```
<head>
   <title>Tableau 1</title>
</head>

    <body>

        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://tableau.com'>

        </script>

<div class='tableauPlaceholder' style='width: 1000px; height: 1227px;'>
    <object class='tableauViz' width='1000' height='1227' style='display:none;'>

        var FILTER1 = "'car'"

        <param name='host_url' value='tableau.com' /> 
        <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' /> <param name='site_root' value='' />
        <param name='name' value='HiHi' />
        <param name='tabs' value='no' /><param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
        <param name='showAppBanner' value='false' />
        <param name='filter' value= FILTER1 />
    </object>
</div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Place the javascript variable inside `<script>` tag

Comment: Should i write  instead of " <param name='filter' value= FILTER1 />" this   <param name='filter' value= + FILTER1  + />?